# How to use C# class in VB.NET project in windows application?

Tags: vb.net

I wanna use the C# code file in VB.Net project Which is windows based application. But that C# class is not using in VB.NET application. How Can I perform this task.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do you want to include the C# file as a resource (like you would do with an image or XML file for example)?

Comment: I have a C# file as Data Access Layer and I wanna use that in my vb.net windows application. I know how to use different languages classes in asp.net. But I am unable to use in windows applicaton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also add the reference for an executable, if it is a .NET assembly. So just compile your C# project and add it as reference into your VB project.

Comment: Thanks,I know this thing. But As we use vb.net individual class in C# project of ASP.NET. Then we put it in APP_Code's Child Directory and Specify it in web.config's compilation->codeSubDirectories tag. Same I wanna use single class of C# to vb.net windows application.

Comment: Well then I don't think that you can do it, except for web projects. I think you have to reference some kind of assembly. How about adding a new C# project into your solution and just add your existing .cs file, compile it as Dll and add the reference.

Answer (score 13):

Compile the C# class in it's own C# class library (DLL) and then in your VB project, add a reference to the C# DLL. You can then use the class in your VB project.

If, however, you want to include the source code of the C# class in your VB project then you will have to convert the class from C# to VB.  There are various methods of doing this, such as the online tool [Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: I don't want to make library because that is a single class.

Comment: @Deepak - I have added the second paragraph in response to your comment

Comment: Thanks, I have converted that code and it is also running but As well as we can do in ASP.NET so I want to use this like web application reference.

Comment: @Deepak - sorry I don't understand the last part of your comment

Comment: I meant to say as we get reference of different language class file in asp.net to put it in APP_code's sub directory and do configuration in web.config's compilation tag. AS like can we do in windows application by any technique?

Comment: if I understand you correctly then the answer is no, you cannot include a C# source code file in a VB Windows application in the way you can with a web site. You will have to use one of the tecnhiques I describe in my answer

Answer (score 13):

It is very simple to combine your VB.net & C#.net project.

**Step1**- Add projects which you wanna combine to a single solution.

**Step2**- Within any one project VB/C# in which you want to call classes from other language    project "**Goto- Add Reference- Projects**" and select the other project which will be automatically displayed.

**Step3**- After adding the reference just add "Imports (in VB)" or "using (in C#)" statements to your code.

**Step4**- bingooo!!! now you can use your VB/C# classes in another language.

(**tip**: You can go only in one direction here i.e. either you can use your C# classes in VB.net or vice versa.)

All the best

Comment: I'll only clarify on steps 1 & 2 - First add C# project to your VB solution (via solution explorer) then from the VB project's properties, add a reference to the project. You can then access the class public methods directly or via a namespace if any (and they'll be compiled into the code!)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, check this:
http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/49259-mixing-vb-net-c-same-project

> However, it is possible to use
>   different languages in a single
>   project. You may need to write command
>   line build file to build the project.
>   In .NET framework SDK, there is one
>   sample on it. You could access it in
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   .NET\FrameworkSDK\Samples\Technologies\CrossDevLan
>   guage.
>
> This sample demonstrates the use
>   different development languages in a
>   single project. This sample creates
>   two assemblies. The first is a library
>   or DLL assembly that defines a simple
>   base class written in managed
>   extensions for C++. The second
>   assembly is an executable assembly
>   that defines three derived classes
>   written in C#, VB, and IL
>   (Intermediate Language). These types
>   derive from each other and ultimately
>   from the base class written in managed
>   C++. Finally, the executable creates
>   instances of each of the derived types
>   and calls a virtual method for each.
>   The .NET Framework is an environment
>   where various developers can work
>   together seamlessly while developing
>   in their language of choice.