# Visual Basic 2010 Markdown implementation

Tags: vb.net, markdown

I just found Markdown for C#. Is there a way I can use C# code in VB.NET?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220501/62576); it may help.

Comment: You use C# code in VB.NET every day, the .NET Framework was written in C#.  So create a C# class library project and add it to your solution.

Comment: Or you can convert the C# code to VB.NET. Though the solution of @HansPassant is preferable.

Comment: @Hans Passant I never worked with c# so this would be a way i dont want to go or am i getting something wrong?

Comment: You don't "work" with it, you are using somebody else's code.  So what could possibly be the point of not doing it this way?

Comment: @Hans Passant Didn't you say "create a C# class library"? The point is i can't C#. Or do you mean, I can include the C# class library into my  VB project?