# Is it possible to call a vb function from C# (same project)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a hybrid MVC/Webforms project created in VS 1013 with both vb and C#. I need to call vb functions from my C# code. Currently this does not seem to work, I cannot access vb functions or classes from C# or visa-versa.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: They can't be in the same project.  Assemblies are either VB or C# (or some other CLR language).  Do you mean same solution?

Comment: "project" or "solution"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220501/how-to-use-c-sharp-class-in-vb-net-project-in-windows-application

Comment: I have vb and C# in the same **project** and I want to call VB functions from C# and visa-versa.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you stay [CLS Compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhc3fa7f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you should be able to use public methods declared in VB.NET assemblies directly from C#, and vice versa.

```
using System;

// Assembly marked as compliant.
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

// Class marked as compliant.
[CLSCompliant(true)]
public class MyCompliantClass {
   // ChangeValue exposes UInt32, which is not in CLS.
   // A compile-time warning results.
   public void ChangeValue(UInt32 value){ }

   public static void Main( ) {
   int i = 2;
   Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
```

Some language features (like parameterized properties, for example, only available in VB.NET) are not available in both languages, so you'll have to watch out for those.  But CLS Compliance is a very conservative approach; if you avoid language-specific features, you really ought to be able to just compile the assemblies, reference one from the other, and just use the methods across assemblies without any further effort.

I don't think you can mix C# code and VB.NET code in the same assembly, so you'll have to put your C# code in one project and your VB.NET code in another.